# PHP serialization error with ' " counts as two characters

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I'm having problems with php serialization, when ever ' " are included i get an extra character space. Ex if it's 6 characters i get 7

```
   $episodes_count = sizeof($episode_title);
$episodes = array();
$content = '';

for ($i = 0; $i <= $episodes_count; $i++) {
    $title = htmlspecialchars($episode_title[$i], ENT_QUOTES);
    $airdate    = $episodes_airdates[$i];
    $season    = $episodes_seasons[$i];
    $number    = $episodes_numbers[$i];
    $plot    = $episodes_plot[$i];

    // check if empty
    if (!empty($title) && !empty($number ) && !empty($plot )) {
        $episodes[] = array(
            'title' => $title, 
            'airdate' => $airdate,
            'season' => $season,
            'number'   => $number,
            'plot'   => $plot,
        );
    }
}

// Serialized Episodes in case they exist, if not, remove the goal post
if ( sizeof($episodes) > 0 ) {
    $content = str_replace("'", '%',serialize($episodes));
}


update_post_meta($post_id, 'episodes', $content);
}
```

Comment: People use `sizeof()`? :) So are you just trying to trim excess white-space or escape single and double quotes from the titles?

Comment: Don't expect wordpress to handle your serialized looking string as not-serialized. Post metas get automatically serialized, which might or might not happen then and when this is read in again it will be rated as serialized, but because you've changed the string, it will get broken.

Comment: @MetalFrog Yes i use sizeof(), lol. To answer your other question, I was trying to eliminate the white space.

Comment: @hakre I'm not quite sure what you mean? I wasn't really depending on WordPress to handle the serialized data.

Comment: @Craig: But you do here: `update_post_meta` <- that's wordpress and you pass that data in there.

Comment: @hakre Oh wow, yes you are right. what would you recommend?

Comment: you can prefix the string with `@@@` or `___`, that should fool wordpress. The hardcore method is to use `base64_encode`.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the suggestion of the base64_encode, it worked like a charm! I've been trying to solve this problem for the past 2 days. It solved both the problems with html special character's white space and with wordpress breaking the metadata on saving by Serializing the already serialized data.

Comment: @Craig: I added this as an answer, normally `base64_encode` is very good for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass some data that looks serialized to wordpress to `update_post_meta` - wordpress can have a problem with that and the data will get broken while stored and retrieved.

To prevent that, you can prefix the string so that it does not look serialized any longer or you even encode the whole string, e.g. with [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode). That will prevent wordpress and other components to modify the values due to encoding issues.

Comment: This should be submitted as a bug in Wordpress.

Comment: @EmilVikström: This has already been reported but there is no concensus to fix it because it's actually by design.